# Как подключать кнопки в BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android

Не понятно как это происходит именно в BottomNavigationView. Хотелось бы узнать у более опытных. Язык программирования использую Java. А также как регулировать расстояние между иконками(кнопками) в BottomNavigationView.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтоб заполнить ваш `BottomNavigationView`, для начала в макете укажите для `BottomNavigationView` откуда брать ресурсы с элементами меню при помощи атрибута `app:menu`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
   android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
   ...
   app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

Ваш `bottom_navigation_menu.xml` с описанным меню может выглядеть так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <item
      android:id="@+id/action_first"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_first"
      android:title="@string/text_first"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

   <item
      android:id="@+id/action_second"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_second"
      android:title="@string/text_second"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

   <item
      android:id="@+id/action_third"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_third"
      android:title="@string/text_third"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Этого достаточно, чтоб наполнить `BottomNavigationView` кнопками. Обработка нажатий кнопок будет происходит следующим образом:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.action_first:
            break;
         case R.id.action_second:
            break;
         case R.id.action_third:
            break;   
      }
      return true;
   }
});
```

Расстояние между иконками контролирует сам BottomNavigationView. Когда количество элементов меню больше трёх, скрываются подписи всех элементов, кроме выбранного. Так же учтите, что максимальное возможное количество элементов равно 5.